# Undefined Variable for my calculator

Tags: java, variables

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class SolverTester
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String symbolSubtract;
    String symbolMultiply;
    String symbolAddition;
    String symbolDivide;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your equation: ");
    int numberFirst = sc.nextInt();
    if(sc.findInLine("-").equals("-"))
    {
        symbolSubtract = sc.findInLine("-");
    } else if(sc.findInLine("*").equals("*"))
    {
        symbolMultiply = sc.findInLine("*");
    } else if(sc.findInLine("+").equals("+"))
    {
        symbolAddition = sc.findInLine("+");
    } else if(sc.findInLine("/").equals("/"))
    {
        symbolDivide = sc.findInLine("/");
    }
    int numberSecond = sc.nextInt();
    Solver s = new Solver(numberFirst, numberSecond);
    if(symbolSubtract.equals("-"))
    {
        s.subtraction();
        System.out.println(s.getAnswer());
    } else if(symbolMultiply.equals("*"))
    {
        s.multiplication();
        System.out.println(s.getAnswer());
    } else if(symbolDivide.equals("/"))
    {
        s.division();
        System.out.println(s.getAnswer());
    } else if(symbolAddition.equals("+"))
    {
        s.addition();
        System.out.println(s.getAnswer());
    }
}
```

}

My error is "variable "symbolSubtract" has not been initialized". The main class is not relevant because the error is involving local variables.

NOTE: This is not a homework assignment... I am just doing it for fun.

Comment: You need to initialize your variable.

Comment: It's just as the error states, you haven't initialized symbolSubtract and then you're trying to compare it to "-"

Comment: Local variables are not initialised for you in the same way that member variables are - when you have an uninitialised local variable you need to ensure that *every* path through that method initialises that variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(sc.findInLine("-").equals("-"))
{
    symbolSubtract = sc.findInLine("-");
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---conditional initialization
```

Only if that `if()` succeeds will the variable get a value.

But on this line

```
if(symbolSubtract.equals("-"))
```

you ALWAYS access the variable, meaning that only SOME of the time will it have a value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialized your variables like this

```
String symbolSubtract="-";
String symbolMultiply="*";
String symbolAddition="+";
String symbolDivide="/";
```

or

```
String symbolSubtract=null;
String symbolMultiply=null;
String symbolAddition=null;
String symbolDivide=null;
```

The second way often result in NPE if you do any operation on it.

Other problem is findInLine(String) read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findInLine(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

If `sc.findInLine("-")` does not equal `"-"`, `symbolSubtract` never gets initialized, so you can't use it. The easiest way around this, IMHO, is just to initialize it with a default value:

```
String symbolSubtract = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you change this:

```
String symbolSubtract;
String symbolMultiply;
String symbolAddition;
String symbolDivide;
```

to this

```
String symbolSubtract = "";
String symbolMultiply = "";
String symbolAddition = "";
String symbolDivide = "";
```

It should work.